# Having awk act upon results from a system command

Tags: awk

I have found some excellent help here about hoe to invoke external commands from within awk and store results in a variable. What I have not been able to find is how to have awk act upon the result as it would on an ordinary input text file.

I use awk to parse a small HTML file (the status page of a running Tahoe LAFS node) in order to find some IP addresses listed. On each IP address I run an nmap scan of a specific port to see if it is open (yes, this is to become an automated Tahoe LAFS grid monitor). Using an if statement I can pick out the line of the output from nmap that contains the status (open/filtered/closed) of the port as its second field (typically "8098/TCP open unknown"). I would like to strip the line of fields 1 and 3 and only keep field 2, however, $2 of course refers to the fields in the HTML file I use as input to my awk script. I tried a user defined function which just did return $2, but that also refers to the field in the input HTML file.

Is there a way to refer to fields in an internally created variable inside an awk script? Something like a nested awk command within an awk script?

Comment: Post your input data, expected output and if possible your own attempt to build a solution.

Comment: What OS are you on? This sounds like it may be a job best not done entirely within an awk script.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. I realize this perhaps would better done outside awk, but I really like awk's ability for simple regexp matching and parsing. A neater solution might be to just write output from my awk parser to a file and call the awk script within a shell script. But now that I started...

Comment: No, that would not be a neater solution but it's not the only alternative. If you post some sample input and expected output as @anubhava requested we could start to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `getline` "function".  It sets `$0` to the entire record and `$1` through `$NF` in the usual way:

```
$ awk '/test/ {
>     while (("ping -c 2 google.com") | getline > 0) {
>         printf("$1 = %s, $2 = %s\n", $1, $2);
>     }
> }'
abc
test
$1 = PING, $2 = google.com
$1 = 64, $2 = bytes
$1 = 64, $2 = bytes
$1 = , $2 = 
$1 = ---, $2 = google.com
$1 = 2, $2 = packets
$1 = round-trip, $2 = min/avg/max/stddev
xyz  
$
```

Edit: added parentheses around `(cmd | getline)` (it works for me without them but I guess some awk variants require it?).

Edit 2: apparently the "parentheses around getline" thing comes from a quite different issue noted in the [GNU awk manuals](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe):

> According to POSIX, ‘expression | getline’ is ambiguous if expression contains unparenthesized operators other than ‘$’—for example, ‘"echo " "date" | getline’ is ambiguous because the concatenation operator is not parenthesized. You should write it as ‘("echo " "date") | getline’ if you want your program to be portable to all awk implementations.

In this case, the expression before the pipe is a single string, so there is no ambiguity.  I moved the parentheses to where they would be needed for a more complex expression.

Also, it's a good idea to call `close()` on the command after the `while` loop exits.  If there is another line matching `test`, awk will assume the existing sub-command should be read further, unless it has been `close()`d.  As the command match is via the string, it's even better, rather than parenthesizing the left hand side of the pipe-to-getline, to store it in a variable and use that variable as an argument to `close`.  For example:

```
awk '/^test / {
    cmd = sprintf("ping -c %d %s", $2, $3)
    while (cmd | getline > 0) print
    close(cmd)
}'
```

(a variant without the semicolons that some dislike :-) ), which, when fed:

```
test 1 google.com
```

produces:

```
PING google.com (74.125.225.161): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.225.161: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=22.898 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 22.898/22.898/22.898/0.000 ms
```

Addendum (poking around on the web, I discovered that this is less obvious than I thought it was): be aware that this kind of "bare" `getline`, because it replaces the "current line", causes any remaining pattern-and-action rules in the script to fire on the *new* line contents.  E.g., after the above, `$0` begins with `round-trip min/av` , so a subsequent rule of the form `/^round/` would match, even though the input line that triggered the "ping" was `test 1 google.com`.  If this is not the last rule, it's probably appropriate to add a `next` directive to it.  (In a complicated script I'd put that in every `getline`-ing action, even the last one, in case the last rule is moved, or more are added.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!! I had tried print but not printf. Interestingly, just doing printf($2) prints the second field of the HTML input file, but printf("",$2) prints the entire row of the getline. I'll continue investigating, but now I at least know where to start!

Comment: Ok, figured out my main mistake: I redirected the output of getline into a variable. That caused temporary field reference to be invalid, so all $2 expressions referred to my HTML input file instead. Now it works as it should. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Also, I was wrong about the printf("",$2) - it did not print anything; what I saw was a forgotten print command later in the script.

Comment: That's the wrong syntax for calling getline (missing parens), printf is a builtin not a function, and the semicolon at the end of the printf line is doing nothing. If you're considering using getline make sure you fully understand all the caveats at http://awk.info/?tip/getline. Using getline is usually the wrong approach so just make sure you've thought it through. So far, I don't even understand what the question is!

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! If it makes things less obfuscated, the script can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6re3l1sranipuy/check_nodes.awk

Comment: I am reluctant to post the HTML file I use as input because it contains IP-addresses used by friends.

Comment: I just read some of the excellent info you linked and I think getline is the proper way to do what I want. I do not direct it to a variable, because I want to reference a field in the output of getline. Is there a way to reference a field in a variable?

Comment: @EdMorton: The above worked for me in testing, I guess some awk variants need parentheses and some don't.  As for printf and the semicolon: that's just the way I prefer to write it.  I only leave out "unnecessary" semicolons in very short command line scripts; I wanted this one to look better.

Comment: @torek no they all need parentheses, they make awk behave correctly in rainy day scenarios rather than spinning off into an infinite loop.

Comment: @EdMorton: d'oh, I was reading the precedence upside down (prev comment nuked).  However, in this particular awk grammar, `pattern '|' GETLINE GT pattern` can still only be parsed such that `pattern '|' GETLINE` is handled as a unit.  So it should wind up binding the same way regardless of parentheses—`while ("cmd" | (getline > 0))` results in a parse error.

Comment: The issue I'm talking about is that you should use `while ((cmd | getline) > 0)` not `while (cmd | getline > 0)`. Sorry, I don't recall the details on exactly what the problem is with the latter (whether it's specific awks or specific input file status or something that can happen with the pipe or something else), google it if you like. I think I heard about it while I was writing http://awk.info/?tip/getline interacting with the other regulars at comp.lang.awk so maybe searching that in google groups would help if you care.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't detail why but the best awk reference book, Effective Awk Programming (http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fPipe), uses the `while ((cmd | getline) > 0)` syntax.

Comment: I now have my awk script doing what I want. It parses the HTML code and picks out IP numbers and port numbers. These are the used by an nmap external command run from within awk, the output of which is piped to getline and is then parsed by awk to pick out port status.

Answer (score 0):

As the relevant part of my final awk script is too large to fit as a comment, I'll post as an answer. The stripInputRecord, getIpNumber and getPortNumber functions just pick out the useful parts from the HTML code.

```
/address/ {
    ip = stripInputRecord( $0 );
    ip = getIpNumber( ip );
    port[na] = stripInputRecord( $0 );
    port[na] = getPortNumber( port[na] );
    if (!(ip~"N/A")) {
            if (ip~/loopback/) {
                    ip="127.0.0.1";
                    port[na]=stdp;
            }
            cmd="nmap -PN -p "stdp" "ip
            cmd2="nmap -PN -p " port[na] " " ip
            while ((cmd | getline)==1) {
                    if ($0~stdp) {
                            stdportstatus[na] = $2
                    }
            }
            while ((cmd2 | getline)==1) {
                    if ($0~port[na]) {
                            otherportstatus[na] = $2
                    }
            }
    }
    close(cmd)
    close(cmd2)
    if ($0~/N\/A/) {
            stdportstatus[na] = "-";
            otherportstatus[na] = "-";
    }
    na++;
```

}

Thank you all (especially torek!)